# How can detect that file uploading has been finished with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I detect that file uploading has been finished?
I use php and jQuery.

Comment: How are you uploading the file?

Comment: I post it with a html form with jQuery and AJAX

Comment: So you are using the new HTML5 features to upload them?

Comment: form action="upload.php" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename: </label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

Comment: That does not really answer my question. Maybe if you post your jQuery code, we can help more. So far we have no idea how you are uploading the files. Before HTML5 you could not upload files with Ajax, and one had to use tricks like hidden iframes. We cannot help you much until we know what technique you are using. Please provide more information.

Comment: So probably without HTML 5 features but why do you want to detect the current state of uploading when your form will load a new site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $ajax command (or $.post or whatever variant you are using) will provide for you to supply a call back function -- define that function, and you will know when it is called that the upload has finished.

See the [success parameter on the jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) command or the [complete function in the ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call